# How to select current items in pyqt5 QlistWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Im using qt designer and have a qlistwidget populated from a db. I want to be able to select from the list and at the moment just print it out. Im using the currentItem method but its not returning a string. It returns only the memory location. I don't understand how to get this to work properly.

```
        session_name_=str(self.listWidget.currentItem())

        addendant_=self.listWidget_2.currentRow()
        scheduled_=self.dateTimeEdit.dateTime()
        sched=scheduled_.toString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm ap")
        
        print(session_name_)
```

It returns
`<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem object at 0x7fe5050bccd0>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use: `session_name = self.listWidget.currentItem().text()`

Comment: yes that work, any idea how to select multiple and print them all out?

Comment: Sorry I don't know that, maybe the documentation of Qt can help you there (it is written for C++ but can easily translated to python because names of functions and classes are the same.) QListWidget: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html

Comment: If you struggle with the translation from C++ to python, maybe this Question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60422323/where-is-the-pyqt5-documentation-for-classes-methods-and-modules

Comment: ok thank you I have been looking at those docs unfortunately I don't have enough experience to know how to manage it, I did'nt see the option in the docs that you could use the .text either. I need more experience and time with this framework

Comment: If what you need is to get all selected items, you should have specified it in your question. Since what is returned is a QListWidgetItem, you need to look at its [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html). Consider that while the Qt docs are aimed for C++, 99% of times the functions and returned values are the same in PyQt/PySide.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get all the selected items, you have to use the view's [`selectionModel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel). The [`selectedIndexes()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedIndexes) returns a list of *unique* [QModelIndexes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html) which is not sorted:

```
selection = self.listWidget.selectionModel()
indexes = sorted(selection.selectedIndexes(), key=lambda i: i.row())
for index in indexes:
    print(index.data())
```